# Need help to prove that a given matrix has a given rank.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

For any positive integer $k$, there is a matrix $M_k$ of size $2^k\times 2^k$ such that each rows and columns of $M_k$ correspond to some subset of $2^{[k]}$. Let $M_k[S][S']$ $(S,S'\subseteq [k])$ denote the element in the row corresponding to subset $S$ and column corresponding to subset $S'$ of $M_k$. $M_k$ is defined such that $M_k[S][S']=1 $ if $2|S\cap S'|=|S'|$ otherwise zero. I have to prove that the rank of $M_k$ is $2^{k-1}$. 
It can be seen that columns corresponding to subsets of odd size have only zeros and rows corresponding to any subset $S$ and $[k]\setminus S$ are equal. So, now a submatrix of $M$ of size $2^{k-1}\times 2^{k-1}$ can be formed by taking columns corresponding to subsets of even size and by taking only one of the two rows corresponding to any subset $S$ or $[k]\setminus S$. Now, the problem is reduced to proving that this new matrix is full rank.

Comment: "can be formed by taking columns corresponding to subsets of odd size " ... should that be "can be formed by taking columns corresponding to subsets of **even** size "? Otherwise, per your argument, all entries in the column will be zero.

Comment: Yeah. My bad. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Amritanshusingh What makes you sure that the rank is indeed $2^{k-1}$ and in what context did you encounter this problem?

Comment: @ΑΘΩ I have checked that this holds for k=1 to k=15 through a program. So, I have a strong felling that the rank is indeed $2^{k-1}$. I encountered this as a constraint matrix of a system of linear equations that I was trying to solve.